# How i launch a Google-Chrome Session from an SSH connection

Tags: ssh, selenium-webdriver, headless

Ey guys, im trying to use selenium/Google Chrome to automate some development and testing task. what i want to do is to avoid any X remote session or even VNC to the server, jsut let for example python launch my app that connects to selenium engine under Chrome Browser.

My problem is that of course when im on my ssh session if i try to launch google-chrome or even my selnium plugin i get browser_main_loop.cc(240)] Gtk: cannot open display .

there is anyway that i can send this command to an already opened X session and get the results back?

Thanks!